# Can I set value=1 item in dropdown as default item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
ViewBag.UserStatusList = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem{Text = "Active", Value = "1",Selected=true},
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Inactive", Value = "0",Selected=false }
};
```

the above shows the viewbag which i am binding to dropdown list . So here I want to fix **Active** as default item in the view page. How can I do that please give some suggestions

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserStatus, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.UserStatusList, new { @id = "ddlCustomerStatusList", @class = "form-control", @selected = "selected" })
```

This is my view

Comment: Show your view (setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is pointless if your correctly binding to a model property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value of your model property in the GET method before you return the view

```
model.UserStatus = 1;
return View(model);
```

You can delete setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` because its ignored by the `DropDownListFor()` method (internally the method builds a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` based on the value of the property your binding to)

Note also you should delete `new { @selected = "selected" }`(that is not a valid attribute for a `<select>` element) and there is no need to use `new { @id = "ddlCustomerStatusList" }` as the helper already creates an `id` attribute (its `id="UserStatus"`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply I did the changes but still i am getting inactive as default item , is there anything else which I am missing.? Consider me as a beginner

Comment: It is working when i put model.UserStatus=1 before my viewbag. Thanks a lot

Comment: You should not be using `ViewBag`. You should be using a [view model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) with a property for the `SelectList` so its strongly typed (refer [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o))